# Social Engine render form issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I'm adding some pages to default layout editor in SE4. What I do is just adding pages to core_pages table and editing core_content table to add a main container and a middle/right two columns layout. Everything works fine, but now I'm adding default Create Video page (videos_index_create) and I got some problems.

When I add this page via sql, I can obviously see and edit page layout by default layout editor. Actually, when I save changes these don't reflect to live page. If I go to the controller (*Video/controllers/IndexController.php*) and add

```
$this->_helper->content->setNoRender()
```

live page displays right sidebar and middle content, but with

```
$this->_helper->content->setEnabled()
```

it shows only the default video upload form.

So I edited *create.tpl* here

```
<?php if (($this->current_count >= $this->quota) && !empty($this->quota)):?>
<div class="tip">
<span>
  <?php echo $this->translate('You have already uploaded the maximum number of videos allowed.');?>
  <?php echo $this->translate('If you would like to upload a new video, please <a href="%1$s">delete</a> an old one first.', $this->url(array('action' => 'manage'), 'video_general'));?>
</span>
</div>
<br/>
<?php else:?>
<?php echo $this->form->render($this); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Changing the else deleting the echo statement and adding a simple **echo 'foo';**. Now, live page shows properly my layout (middle+right) with default content ("foo").

I figured thus that the issue is about this line in controller:

```
$this->view->form = $form = new Video_Form_Video();
```

but I can't go further… this custom form class (*Video/Form/Video.php*) seems nothing special, I can't really figure out why its rendering crushes default layout render.

Any social engine expert right here to help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

If its a Zend_Form I am pretty sure you should be doing:

```
<?php echo $this->form;?>
```

In your view not call render yourself.
If it is NOT a Zend_Form please post the code for the form it probably has some css or whatnot breaking your layout.